# Deleting all old files after rebuilding world on FreeBSD

Tags: software-installation, compiling, freebsd

I'm rebuilding world and would like to have every other file not created by the rebuilding of world to be deleted. Is there some mergemaster option for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `make` targets `delete-old` and `delete-old-libs` to remove obsolete files. They run interactively, unless you set `BATCH_DELETE_OLD_FILES`:

```
# pwd
/usr/src
# make -DBATCH_DELETE_OLD_FILES delete-old
```

Run them after `make installworld`.

Have a look at build(7) for more details.

A word of warning - be careful with `delete-old-libs` - it will delete anything that was not built as part of the current world/kernel so if any of your installed ports rely on older versions of any system libs, you'll need to reinstall the affected ports. I usually run `delete-old-libs` after a complete port rebuild to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to be sure, though, would it delete literally everything that isn't from the build?

Comment: They will only delete obsolete files that were installed as part of the base system - executables, headers, documentation, etc. `delete-old-libs` will only delete obsolete shared libraries. You can use the target `check-old` to see what the other two would delete.